# Filtering a query with subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In order to understand the question I will explain the result expected.
I have a db table where I save some data of the activity of the current day. Then I want to sum some numeric fields and the last register of the text fields, using a filter between two dates.

Example:

```
       •DB TABLE

  ID|CALLS|RESULT  |  DATE

  1 | 2   |FAIL    |15/09/16
  1 | 1   |ERROR   |16/09/16
  1 | 3   |OK      |17/09/16


      •SUM BETWEEN 15 and 17

 ID|TOTAL CALLS|LAST RESULT   
 1 |    6      |    OK   

     •SUM BETWEEN 15 and 16

 ID|TOTAL CALLS|LAST RESULT   
 1 |    3      |  ERROR
```

-Would this be the solution?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ID,
 TOTAL_CALLS=SUM(CALLS),
 LAST_RESULT= (
     SELECT RESULT FROM TABLE T2 where T2.DATE between MIN(T1.DATE) and MAX (T1.DATE) and T1.ID=T2.ID
)

FROM TABLE T1
WHERE
TIME BETWEEN 15/09/16 and 17/09/16
GROUP BY ID
```

Thank you very much!

Regards

Comment: what is your final output based on your sample table

Comment: The desired solution would be 1 (ID) |6 (CALLS) | OK (RESULT) . In case that the TIME LAST DATE were 16/09/16 the solution would be 1 (ID) |3 (CALLS) | ERROR(RESULT). Sorry for the text format. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query.

```
;WITH cte_1
AS
(SELECT  ID,SUM(CALLS)OVER( PARTITION BY ID) [TOTAL CALLS] 
 ,Result [LAST RESULT]
 ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [DATE] desc) RNO
from #YourTable T
WHERE [DATE] between '09/15/2016' AND '09/16/16')
SELECT ID,[TOTAL CALLS],[LAST RESULT] 
FROM cte_1 
WHERE Rno=1
```

Comment: Almost there, but I need to group by the ID. There are a lot of different ID so the main query must be a SELECT DISTINCT. If I use that structure I must use the GROUP BY DATE and that shows more than one row per ID. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use TOP 1 WITH TIES with ORDERING to get what you need:

```
DECLARE @dFrom date = '2016-09-15',
        @dTo date = '2016-09-16'

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
                    ID,
                    SUM(CALLS) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) [TOTAL CALLS],
                    RESULT [LAST RESULT]
FROM YourTable
WHERE [DATE] between @dFrom and @dTo
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [DATE]) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use max date to get result column value.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME= '15 SEP 2016'

DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME= '16 SEP 2016'

SELECT ID , SUM(CALLS) , ( SELECT RESULT
                           FROM #yourTable
                           WHERE [DATE] = @ToDate
                         )  RESULT
FROM **#yourTable**
WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
GROUP BY ID
```